# Connecting to AWS documentDB using mongoose giving error: 'MongoParseError: option ssl_ca_certs is not supported'

Tags: node.js, mongodb, amazon-web-services, mongoose

Hello I am just trying to connect to my documentDb using mongoose; hosted on AWS. From my local pc, I am try to do it like:

```
const URI = 'mongodb://username:npassword@docdb-2022-05-31-18-46-43.cluster-cnyrbefiq91q.eu-west-2.docdb.amazonaws.com:27017/?ssl=true&replicaSet=rs0&readPreference=secondaryPreferred&retryWrites=false'

mongoose.connect(URI, { useNewUrlParser: true , ssl: true});
```

I am getting the error:

```
MongoParseError: option ssl_ca_certs is not supported
```

Can any1 explain to me what I am doing wrong?

Comment: Your connection string has the parameter `ssl=true`.  This means the monogd process in AWS DocumentDB must have a server running with SSL support turned on and certs available.

Comment: @barrypicker yes it does, by default

Comment: Also running into this

Comment: Yep also running into this... any ideas here? using node mongo driver `"mongodb": "^4.3.1"`

Comment: same here, any solutions?

Comment: Just want to add, we eventually gave up and switched to mongoDb Atlas

Answer (score 12, accepted):

DocumentDB supports TLS protocol. It worked for me when I

1/ downloaded the TLS public key using

```
wget https://s3.amazonaws.com/rds-downloads/rds-combined-ca-bundle.pem
```

2/ changed the parameter `ssl=true` to `tls=true` in the connection string,

3/ and updated the params to connect() method.

```
const uri = 'mongodb://<user>:<password>@<clusterAddress>:27017/?tls=true&replicaSet=rs0&readPreference=secondaryPreferred&retryWrites=false'
const client = new MongoClient(uri,{tlsCAFile: `rds-combined-ca-bundle.pem`});

try{
    await client.connect();
}
```

I referred to [this](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/documentdb/latest/developerguide/connect_programmatically.html#connect_programmatically-tls_enabled) DocumentDB documentation.

Comment: I havnt tested this (as not working on this anymore) but will accept as answer so other people can see

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue, which I resolved by following method.

```
 mongodb://username:password@host_cluster:port_number/database_name?tls=true&ssl=true&tlsCAFile=xyz.bundle.pem&retryWrites=false&replicaSet=replicaSetName
```

Answer (score 0):

Try sslCA insted of ssl_ca_certs.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: `option sslca is not supported`